# Can someone explain to me how this simplification of a fraction works?

Tags: fractions

Can someone explain to me why is the answer $30b^{3}/4(a+b)$ considering that on the previous line we multiply $[5b][a+b]/{[4][6b^2]}$. It's as if we multiply the numerator of the first term with the denominator of the second term. Is there a special rule that I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line in the process you have described is just wrong.  You seem to correctly understand that the result is $\frac{5ab+5b^2}{24b^2}$.

Comment: So it's safe to assume that there are mistakes in the book I'm using? Because this is not the first suspicious answer that I have encountered.

Comment: Given what you have put in your Question, there is at least one mistake in the book you are using.